# Display images through html img tag with angularjs and ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm currently doing an hybrid mobile app with [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and Angularjs and i'm trying to display images through an img html tag. My page is composed of a caroussel at the top (which works well, it displays images) and a list with small images. 
In the controller of my page there is :

```
app.controller('SalleCtrl', function ($scope,$location) {

$scope.salle = {
    "num": "2",
    "imgR": [
        "img/art_affiche_6_thumb-300x300.jpg",
        "img/art_affiche_6_thumb-300x300.jpg"
    ],
    "title": "Salle 2 : Premières peintures",
    "_audio_guide": [],
    "_audio_guide_fe": [],
    "_audio_guide_en": [],
    "artworks": [
        {
            "img": "img/art_affiche_6_thumb-300x300.jpg",
            "href": "http://172.16.12.158/wordpress/mcm_oeuvre/oeuvre-14-2/",
            "title": "Oeuvre 14"
        },
        {
            "img": "img/art_affiche_9_thumb-300x300.jpg",
            "href": "http://172.16.12.158/wordpress/mcm_oeuvre/oeuvre-3/",
            "title": "Oeuvre 3"
        }
    ]
};
});
```

And in my html page there is :

```
<ion-view title="{{salle.title}}">

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content class="has-header" id="" >
    <ul rn-carousel class="image">
         <li ng-repeat="image in salle.imgR" style="background-image:url({{ image }});background-color:black;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;background-size : contain;"> 
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="artwork in salle.artworks" class="item item-avatar" href="{{artwork.href}}">
          <img ng-src="{{artwork.img}}">
          <h2>{{artwork.title}}  {{artwork.img}}</h2>   
        </a>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

When I display it on a browser everything works well. But when I try on my smartphone the caroussel works, it displays images, but the list doesn't show the images, unstead of  {{artwork.img}} show me all the images.
I try to :

1. replace 'ng-src' by 'src' but nothing happens
2. replace ng-src="{{artwork.img}}" by ng-src="img/art_affiche_6_thumb-300x300.jpg" it works.

Apparently the binding is not correctly made... Have you any idea why? And how resolve it?!
Moreover on my smartphone, the path of the images looks like "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/...". The caroussel works well, but the list of image doesn't works, and when I translate "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/..." to "file://mnt/sdcard/..." it works. Why?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally find the answer. The problem is due to the fact that angularjs  [prevent XSS attacks via html link with the function imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider). So the image path which begin with 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent' is prefix by "unsafe:" and so the image is not display. In order to get around this problem I had to override this method, to do that in my config of my main module I add this code :

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
     .config( ['$compileProvider',function( $compileProvider ){ 
         $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s(https|file|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);
       }
     ]);
```

The discussion with the [answer](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/displaying-image-file-from-android-filesystem/1994/5)

Answer (score 4):

---

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by simply referencing the images relative to the index.html file, not absolute referencing based on the URL.

I had `img src="/hello.jpg"` when it needs to be `img src="hello.jpg"`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another situation that can cause the img tag to not resolve.  I was porting an HTML5 webapp to a hybrid app and encountered the issue above, in a view the img tags won't resolve.  In my routing initialization I was calling:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This seems to cause an issue with finding the img src on the local install(unless on android device, I have not tested on IOS ).   Given that this code is not really required unless you are rendering in a browser,  I have removed the code for the hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but I found my self having same problem with Ionic 3. It was resolved simply by changing:

```
    <img ng-src="{{artwork.img}}">
```

to this:

```
    <img ng-src={{artwork.img}}>
```

I hoped this helped someone.